# How to replace xml node value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code, i am using firefox's firebug (console.info)

```
 var productMap = {
    "1": "IIR"        
};

 $(xml).find('ConfigInfo').each(function(){
     var pid = $(this).find('productId').text();    
     $(this).find('productId').text(productMap[pid]);
     console.info($(this).find('productId').text());
 });

 $(xml).find('ConfigInfo').each(function(){
     console.info($(this).find('productId').text());
 });
```

My Xml

```
<list>
<com.abc.db.ConfigInfo>
<cfgId>83</cfgId>
<cfgName>test</cfgName>
<cfgDesc>test</cfgDesc>
<cfgType>test</cfgType>
<fileName>csmclientbenz.xml</fileName>
<absolutePath>../webapps/csm/files//1-105101/csmclientbenz.xml</absolutePath>
<emailAddress>rmargasa@abc.com</emailAddress>
<projectId>1-105101</projectId>
<hostname>benz</hostname>
<createDate>2011-06-15 15:29:55.0 IST</createDate>
<updateDate>2011-06-15 15:29:55.0 IST</updateDate>
<state>1</state>
<productId>1</productId>
</com.abc.db.ConfigInfo>
<com.abc.db.ConfigInfo>
<cfgId>102</cfgId>
<cfgName>cfgname1</cfgName>
<cfgDesc>test</cfgDesc>
<cfgType>test</cfgType>
<fileName>csmclientestilo.xml</fileName>
<absolutePath>../webapps/csm/files//1-105101/csmclientestilo.xml</absolutePath>
<emailAddress>rmargasa@abc.com</emailAddress>
<projectId>1-105101</projectId>
<hostname>estilo</hostname>
<createDate>2011-06-20 18:26:03.0 IST</createDate>
<updateDate>2011-06-20 18:26:03.0 IST</updateDate>
<state>1</state>
<productId>1</productId>
</com.abc.db.ConfigInfo>
</list>
```

My jqGrid code

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml); 
         $('#configDiv').empty();
            $('<div width="100%">')
            .attr('id','configDetailsGrid')
            .html('<table id="list1" width="100%"></table>'+
                    '<div id="gridpager"></div>'+
                '</div>')       
            .appendTo('#configDiv');    

            var grid = jQuery("#list1");

            grid.jqGrid({

              datastr : xml,
              datatype: 'xmlstring',
              colNames:['cfgId','','Name', 'Host', 'Description','Product', 'Type', 'Last Updated Time','Last Updated By',''],
              colModel:[
                  {name:'cfgId',index:'cfgId', width:90, align:"right", hidden:true},
                  {name:'',index:'', width:15, align:"right",edittype:'checkbox',formatter: "checkbox",editoptions: { value:"True:False"},editable:true,formatoptions: {disabled : false}},
                  {name:'cfgName',index:'cfgName', width:90, align:"right"},
                  {name:'hostname',index:'hostname', width:90, align:"right"},
                  {name:'cfgDesc',index:'cfgDesc', width:90, align:"right"},
                  {name:'productId',index:'productId', width:60, align:"right"},
                  {name:'cfgType',index:'cfgType', width:60, align:"right"},
                  {name:'updateDate',index:'updateDate',sorttype:'Date', width:120, align:"right"},
                  {name:'emailAddress',index:'emailAddress', width:120, align:"right"},
                  {name:'absolutePath',index:'absolutePath', width:90, align:"right", hidden:true},
              ],
              pager : '#gridpager',
              rowNum:10,
              scrollOffset:0,
              height: 'auto',

              autowidth:true,
              viewrecords: true,
              gridview: true,
              xmlReader: {
                  root : "list",
                  row: "com\\.abc\\.db\\.ConfigInfo",
                  userdata: "userdata",
                  repeatitems: false
              },
              onSelectRow: function(id,status){
                  var rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(id); 
                  configid = rowData['cfgId'];
                  configname=rowData['cfgName'];
                  configdesc=rowData['cfgDesc'];
                  configenv=rowData['cfgType'];

                  if(status==true)
                  {

                  }

                  rowChecked=1;
                  currentrow=id;
                  },
              onCellSelect: function(rowid, index, contents, event) {
                  if(index==2)
                  {

                        $(xmlDoc).find('list com\\.abc\\.db\\.ConfigInfo').each(function()
                        {
                            //alert($(this).find('cfgId').text()+" "+configid);
                            if($(this).find('cfgId').text()==configid)  
                            {
                                configname=$(this).find('cfgName').text(); 
                                configdesc=$(this).find('cfgDesc').text();
                                configenv=$(this).find('cfgType').text();
                                filename=$(this).find('fileName').text();
                                updatedate=$(this).find('updateDate').text();
                                absolutepath=$(this).find('absolutePath').text();
                                productname=productMap[$(this).find('productId').text()];
                            }
                        });

                  }
               }

            });
            grid.jqGrid('navGrid','#gridpager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
```

This is what i get the output as. **My question**: How to replace an xml's node value?

[image]

**Updated with my solution**

I used `xml=xml.replace(/<productId>1/g, "<productId>"+productMap['1']);` by adding a `/g` it replaced all my string occurances.

Comment: So the problem is that you changed the text but somehow it does not seem to be persistent? What is `xml`?

Comment: @Felix Kling: Ya correct, i posted my xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `xml` is a string. jQuery does not change the string, it only changes the DOM representation it created by parsing it. Every time you pass the string to jQuery, it parses it anew.

You need to keep a reference to the object jQuery creates:

```
var $xml = $(xml);
// now change it using $xml
```

If you want to "serialize" the data again, you have two possibilties:

- Either use the [`outerHTML` plugin](http://darlesson.com/jquery/outerhtml/): `xml = $xml.outerHTML();`
- Or append the whole XML to some dummy element

  ```
  var $xml = $('<dummy />').append(xml);
  ```

  and use `xml = $xml.html();` later.

  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/BKtSV/)

  You can also append it, *after* you did the processing so that this additional element does not brake your current selectors.

**Update:**

I just saw that jQuery also offers [`$.parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) since version 1.5. This might be helpful too.

Comment: it works here, but down the line i am using `xml` in a [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) datasource, which gets affected, and does not display the grid contents at all

Comment: or I can simply use `xml=xml.replace(/<productId>1/g, "<productId>"+productMap['1']);` Thanks it solved my problem